# how can I insert, updatek select, delete datata among three tables and pivote table where many to many ternary relationship exists?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

for example We have 5 sales men, 1000 customers, 5 airlines listed. Now, suppose salesman 1 has sold 5 ticket to 2 customer of three airlines, again same customer has bought 15 ticket of five airlines from 3 salesmen. So it is definitely going to be a ternary many to many relationship in pivote sales table. Now How can entry and retrieve those sales from a single form where all data with relationship would be listed in all four  respective table in the background? Thank you

Comment: ...are you asking us how to design your database?

Comment: yes. that's in laravle